# PHP: How to get internal arguments?

Tags: php, command-line-arguments

Given the command:

```
/usr/bin/php -c /path/to/custom/php.ini /path/to/script.php
```

I'd like to get the internal options:

```
-c /path/to/custom/php.ini
```

Things I've tried that do not work:

- **`$argv`** contains `['/path/to/script.php']`
- **`getopt('c')`** contains `[]`
- **`$_ENV`** does not contain it
- **`$_SERVER`**  does not contain it

I've also looked for a `PHP_*` constant (such as `PHP_BINARY`) but cannot find one for these arguments.

Is there any way to get these arguments? Note that I am not trying to obtain the loaded `ini` file but any arguments that might be present here.

Comment: would suggest var_export($_SERVER) as first port of call, also, that isnt a script argument, so i doubt you will see it, i seem to remember you will only ever see any args that come AFTER the script. also, are you trying to get the custom INI only? or any argument passed to php? if you just want the ini, look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php

Comment: `echo shell_exec('ps -p '.getmypid().' -o args=');`

Answer (score 3):

PHP has no internal way of doing this, so you are going to have to rely on certain system information and permissions.

```
$pid = getmypid();
$ps = `ps aux | grep $pid`;
$command = substr($ps, strpos($ps, '/usr/bin/php'));
$args = explode(' ', $command); //not pretty, should probably use preg
```

Comment: It will do unless `-H` is passed as php argument. Also no need to you can pass `-p pid` to `ps` for specific pid - no need for greping.

Comment: `ps aux | grep pid | grep -v grep | awk '{for(i=11;i<=NF;i++) printf $i" ";printf "\n"}'`

Answer (score 2):

`-c /path/to/custom/php.ini` is an option passed to the PHP parser, interpretator and other internall stuff before even starting your script.

`/path/to/script.php`  is an actual argument passed not only to the PHP executable, but to your script.

Following arguments like `/usr/bin/php -c /path/to/custom/php.ini /path/to/script.php A B C` would also be passed to your script.

Unfortunately the `-c` option is not one of them.

You could get the used `php.ini` file within the executed PHP script by using `get_cfg_var`.

```
echo get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
```

If you are passing the `-c` option you would get the path to your php.ini file. Otherwise you would get the default php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because of how command line BASH arguments are parsed, you won't be able to access the arguments before your script call. Right now, the program `/usr/bin/php` has

```
argv[0]=/usr/bin/php
argv[1]=-c
argv[2]=/path/to/custom/php.ini
argv[3]=/path/to/script.php
```

And that's where your arguments are landing. Your script on the other hand has:

```
argv[0]=/path/to/script.php
```

Just because the arguments are processed right to left, and there are no arguments after your script call.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something as follows since it doesn't require any parsing.

```sh
$ (ARGS="-c /path/to/custom/php.ini"; /usr/bin/php $ARGS /path/to/script.php $ARGS)
```

Comment: Some other script might call it on the command line. An external script is not likely to pass the options as an argument.

Comment: @HaralanDobrev, Yeah, it should be used in a *controlled* environment